# Faucet Water Coming Out Too Slow

Tags: bathroom, faucet, clog

The faucet in my bathroom has become really slow as far as water pressure. I suspect it must be some rock chips clogging up the faucet head.

How can I remove the faucet head so I can clean up the filter? I own another faucet that easily unscrews by hand, but this one is different. I don't know if it's even possible to unscrew the head.

Please advise on what to do or what tools to use. Here are some photos of my faucet:

[image]

From below:
[image]

Comment: Some need the help of pliers(slip joints) to loosen.  Wide rubber band/s wrapped around the head should help prevent scratches.  Can probably be cleaned if you can fix a container with some vinegar, with the head in it soaking for a bit.

Comment: @crip659 -- that's an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Some need the help of pliers(slip joints) to loosen.

Wide rubber band/s wrapped around the head should help prevent scratches.

Can probably also be cleaned if you can fix a container with some vinegar, with the head in it soaking for a bit.

Will take a bit of Macgyvering to fix something to hold it up for maybe an hour.

Make sure the drain is blocked and maybe take pictures if you take it apart

Comment: correct answer and instructions (close the drain)

Comment: maybe add turn to the left, and screw on with fingers only

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is a clogged aerator, it can be removed by unscrewing and the parts cleaned. Sometimes it is hard to remove, in which case a pair of pliers or vice grip (gently used) is in order.

Answer (score 1):

The threads are probably packed with sediment from the water. Reach under the faucet head with a pair of pliers and gentle squeeze, catching the aerator. Then move the pliers in a clockwise direction, looking down. That should loosen it. If you're afraid of scratching the aerator, use a cloth around the aerator before grabbing it with the pliers.